# Switch case gets executed twice

Tags: objective-c, loops, switch-statement

I have the following piece of code : (it's long)

```
//declarations (in the header) :
NSDictionary* batteryRawDict;
@property (strong, atomic, readonly) NSDictionary* batteryReport; //this dictionary is, obviously, @synthesize'd

-(BOOL) refreshGroup:(PFSystemKitGroup)group {
kern_return_t result;
switch (group) {
    case PFSKGroupGraphics: {
        val4Key("graphicReport", [self listGraphics]);
        //break;
    }
    case PFSKGroupBattery: { //to get more informations or to subscribe for events about power sources, use the IOPowerSources API
        if (!firstRunDoneForBattery) {
            batEntry = IOServiceGetMatchingService(masterPort, IOServiceMatching("IOPMPowerSource"));
            if (batEntry == 0) {
                _error = PFSKReturnComponentUnavailable;
                return false;
            }
        }
        CFMutableDictionaryRef  batProps = NULL;
        result = IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperties(batEntry, &batProps, NULL, 0);
        if (result!=kIOReturnSuccess) {
            _error = PFSKReturnIOKitCFFailure;
            _extError = result;
            return false;
        } else {
            batteryRawDict = (__bridge_transfer NSDictionary*)batProps;
            NSMutableDictionary* temp = [NSMutableDictionary.alloc init];
            if (!firstRunDoneForBattery) { //static keys
                //[temp setObject:[batteryRawDict objectForKey:@"DesignCapacity"] forKey:@"DesignedCapacity"];
                [temp setObject:[batteryRawDict objectForKey:@"DesignCycleCount9C"] forKey:@"DesignedCycleCount"];
                [temp setObject:[batteryRawDict objectForKey:@"BatterySerialNumber"] forKey:@"Serial"];
                [temp setObject:[batteryRawDict objectForKey:@"DeviceName"] forKey:@"Model"];
                [temp setObject:[batteryRawDict objectForKey:@"Manufacturer"] forKey:@"Manufacturer"];
                unsigned int manufactureDateAsInt = [[batteryRawDict objectForKey:@"ManufactureDate"] intValue];
                NSDateComponents* manufactureDateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc]init];
                manufactureDateComponents.year = (manufactureDateAsInt >> 9) + 1980;
                manufactureDateComponents.month = (manufactureDateAsInt >> 5) & 0xF;
                manufactureDateComponents.day = manufactureDateAsInt & 0x1F;
                [temp setObject:[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:manufactureDateComponents] forKey:@"ManufactureDate"];
                firstRunDoneForBattery = 1;
            }
            [temp setObject:[batteryRawDict objectForKey:@"BatteryInstalled"] forKey:@"isPresent"];
            [temp setObject:[batteryRawDict objectForKey:@"FullyCharged"] forKey:@"isFull"];
            [temp setObject:[batteryRawDict objectForKey:@"IsCharging"] forKey:@"isCharging"];
            [temp setObject:[batteryRawDict objectForKey:@"ExternalConnected"] forKey:@"isACConnected"];
            [temp setObject:[batteryRawDict objectForKey:@"Amperage"] forKey:@"Amperage"];
            [temp setObject:[batteryRawDict objectForKey:@"CurrentCapacity"] forKey:@"CurrentCapacity"];
            [temp setObject:[batteryRawDict objectForKey:@"MaxCapacity"] forKey:@"MaxCapacity"];
            [temp setObject:[batteryRawDict objectForKey:@"Voltage"] forKey:@"Voltage"];
            [temp setObject:[batteryRawDict objectForKey:@"CycleCount"] forKey:@"CycleCount"];
            [temp setObject:@(([[batteryRawDict objectForKey:@"MaxCapacity"] intValue] / [[batteryRawDict objectForKey:@"DesignCapacity"] intValue])*100) forKey:@"Health"]; //percentage
            [temp setObject:@([[batteryRawDict objectForKey:@"Temperature"] doubleValue] / 100) forKey:@"Temperature"];
            /*to be checked*/[temp setObject:@([[batteryRawDict objectForKey:@"Amperage"] doubleValue] / 1000 * [[batteryRawDict objectForKey:@"Voltage"] doubleValue] / 1000) forKey:@"Power"];
            NSDateComponents* differenceDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitDay
                                            fromDate:[temp objectForKey:@"ManufactureDate"]
                                              toDate:[NSDate date]
                                             options:0];
            [temp setObject:@([differenceDate day]) forKey:@"Age"];
            NSLog(@"--------------------------------------------------------");
            batteryReport = [temp copy];
        }
        _error = PFSKReturnSuccess;
        return true;
    }
}
_error = PFSKReturnSuccess;
return true;
}
```

The problem is, that when control reaches the end of the case, the whole block will be re-executed (thus, the NSLog when appear twice in stdout).

Any idea on why this is happening ?
Thanks !

EDIT : unabridged code

Comment: Show real code, please. What is actually going on here (i.e. the surrounding context).

Comment: If you re-read my comment form your previous question I specifically stated that when you post this question, be sure to provide more context. Just posting a `case` statement with no context doesn't help us help you. And most of the code in the `case` statement is irrelevant to the issue. The problem is why is the `case` being called twice unexpectedly so the body of the case doesn't matter.

Comment: BTW - what debugging have you done to solve this? Put a breakpoint on your log statement and look at the stack trace the two times it stops. See what code path results in it being called twice.

Comment: What `switch` statement??  There is none.

Comment: To all -sorry, I messed up with this question. Gonna update

Comment: Maybe you're receiving the `refreshGroup:` message twice. You need an `NSLog` at the top of the method to check.

Comment: @robmayoff see my answer below, but thanks anyway !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @rmaddy, I looked at the stack trace.

There, I noticed that the case was executed once when expected, but also once *before*, at the same time the previous case... which revealed to be lacking its `break` statement, so control continued executing. In the end, just remember to check that *all* of your cases have a break statement.

*Thanks again to @rmaddy*

Comment: Sometimes you just miss that one break and it causes alot of trouble =)